# cannot use msgs (type <-chan _) as type chan _ in return argument

Tags: go, types, channel

Have following code:

```
func consumeQueue(ch *amqp.Channel, q_Name string) (chan amqp.Delivery) {
    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q_Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        true,   // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")   
    return msgs
}
```

It throws following compile time exception:

```
cannot use msgs (type <-chan amqp.Delivery) as type chan amqp.Delivery in return argument
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly straightforward. You're trying to return a directional channel (in this case a read-only channel) as a general channel that can be used for both reading and writing.

There's some basic information about channel directions [here](https://gobyexample.com/channel-directions)

### Tl;Dr

Any `chan t` can be used as a directional channel. This increases overal typesafety and makes code easier to understand/use for others:

```
func Foo() <-chan struct{} {
}
```

This tells me `Foo` returns a channel I can read from. If it were to return just `chan struct{}`, I'd have to check the docs to see if I'm expected to push something to that channel, or receive from it.

A non-directional channel can be made directional, but it's not allowed to convert back to a non-directional channel for obvious reasons. You can check [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) on channel types for even more details, but the essence of it is this simple sentence:

> The optional <- operator specifies the channel direction, send or receive. If no direction is given, the channel is bidirectional. A channel may be constrained only to send or only to receive by conversion or assignment.

### solution

In your particular case, the solution is simple: change the return type to match the channel you have:

```
func consumeQueue(ch *amqp.Channel, q_Name string) (<-chan amqp.Delivery) {
```

As you've noticed: the compiler shouts at you when you try to convert a directional channel into a bidirectional channel. You'll also get a similar error when you try to convert a read-channel into a write channel (written as `chan<- amqp.Delivery`). So if you get type error messages from the compiler, just check what types it's mentioning... go's compiler spits out pretty self-explanatory errors IMO